# ASP.NET Ajax - $get() does not find input with russian letters in id

Tags: asp.net, ajax

While upgrading AjaxControlToolkit  from version 3.0.20229.0 to version 3.5.51116.0 (the latest one) AutoCompleteExtender stopped working.

Investigation gave me the following html (MicrosoftAjax.debug.js generated by ToolkitScriptManager):

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="MicrosoftAjax.debug.js"></SCRIPT>

<INPUT id="русский_id" >

<SCRIPT language=javascript>
    alert($get("русский_id"));`
    alert(document.getElementById("русский_id"));
</SCRIPT>

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The first alert results in null, the second one works fine.
The code with $get is generated by AutoCompleteExtender, and I cannot use english-only id (the id is generated by external component that I cannot change).

How can I make it work?

***UPDATE***

I have tried in IE6, IE9 and FireFox 10 with the same result.

If I get MicrosoftAjax.debug.js from http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/3.5/MicrosoftAjax.Debug.js (file version 3.5.30729.1) it works, but with the one generated by ToolkitScriptManager (file version 3.5.51116) it doesn't.

Comment: I have tried this code in IE8 and Chrome and they both work. Perhaps creating a jsfiddle example would help.

Comment: Could you please provide details on what exactly you have done to make it work? Where did you get MicrosoftAjax.debug.js (see post update)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found workaround: it works if jQuery library is also included.
MicrosoftAjax calls jQuery functions if available, and they work fine in this case.